# How to setup notification of a degraded RAID array in OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, raid

I just happened to open up disk utility this weekend and it showed that my RAID1 array was degraded because one of the drives failed but I never got any notification of the problem, it could have been like this for weeks :p

How can I setup an automatic alert when a RAID array dies, email or whatever?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I posted a script to do this over on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/153956/mac-os-x-server-10-6-apples-software-mirrored-raid-worth-it/154344#154344).

Answer (score 3):

This functionality doesn't appear to be included in OS X Client, so I use [RaidEye](http://www.hanynet.com/raideye/index.html) to do this on my Mac.  It is no-cost and open source.

Answer (score 0):

What's the hardware platform?

For example, Dell poweredge servers can be ordered with a baseboard management interface which can be polled via SNMP, or via Dell's OMSA utilities. You can then set up a Nagios or similar alerting software to check that the values are in range. For example, one check might look at the health of the RAID array and report if it's anything other than OK. There are Nagios check scripts for most of the common RAID array types.

Comment: The hardware info panel is telling me the SATA controller is Intel ICH10 AHCI